# How can we sort both row-wise ascending and column-wise descending of 2D arrays in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to sort a 2D array both row wise and column wise in Java. Is there a way to do that similar to following python code. I have array as numbers[][2];

python code

```
# it first sorts based on index 0; if they match, it reverse sort based on index 1
numbers.sort(key: lambda x:(x[0], -x[1]))
```

Can we achieve the same in Java through Arrays.sort(), if yes, what will be the comparator that I need to pass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
Arrays.sort(
    numbers, 
    Comparator.comparing((int[] x) -> x[0])
              .thenComparing(
                  (int[] x) -> x[1], 
                  Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder().reversed()));
```

This uses the overload of [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) that receives a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Maybe using a plain lambda expression is better:

```
Arrays.sort(
    numbers, 
    (a, b) -> a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : a[0] > b[0] ?  1 :
              a[1] < b[1] ?  1 : a[1] > b[1] ? -1 : 0);
```